# xmlhttp.responsetext does not work correctly

Tags: javascript

I want to create a random secret and QRcode from secret.
I have some codes for design and some javascripts codes for functions.when I click Create new secret button I see Html tags in textbox instead the secret code.like this:

```
<div align="left">
<label>Google Authenticator Setting</label>
<form>
<br>
secret: <input type="text" id="mysecret" name="secret" value="" >
<br>
<input type="Button" class="elgg_button" value="Create new secret"       width="610px" onclick = "newSecret()" >
<input type="Button" id="qrcodebtn" class="elgg_button" value="Show/Refresh qrcode"   width="610px" onclick = "genQrCode()" >
</form>
<br>
</div>
<div id="qrcode" style="text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right:  auto;width:700px"></div>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), 
{
width : 200,
height : 200
});

var qrurl;

function stringGen(len)
{
var text = "";

var charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567";

for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
    text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

return text;
}

function newSecret()
{
var xstr = "";
qrurl = "";
document.getElementById('mysecret').value = "";

window.XMLHttpRequest
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

//xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
    {
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      xstr=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","mod/test/views/default/test/coder.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();

  if(xstr != "")
{
     var res = xstr.split(";");
    qrurl = res[1];
    document.getElementById('mysecret').value = res[0];

}
else
{
    alert("Empty Str!")
}
}
function genQrCode()
{
if (qrurl=="") 
{
    alert("Generate a text");
    return;
}
qrcode.makeCode(qrurl);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is asynchronous.

This means: You send a request to a server.  It takes some time to get a reply back.  While waiting for a response, the rest of your code is executed.
So you cannot use xstr, just by asuming it exists under (larger line number in the code) xmlhttp.send();

Instead, how Ajax works: you give a callback, a function that will be executed once the response is back.
This function:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    xstr = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
// notice: xstr is empty here
```

You should only use xstr within this function.  Just continue there.  Something like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    xstr = xmlhttp.responseText;
    if(xstr != "") {
      var res = xstr.split(";");
      qrurl = res[1];
      document.getElementById('mysecret').value = res[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer,it's correct and worked in other sites,i understand by your answer that i use elgg functions for solve problem because i write a plugin for elgg.can you help me?if you know about elgg please send a email address.if not please introduce me other people can help me about elgg plugins.thanks a lot:)

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know elgg.  I there are big sites running on elgg; so I presume it's good.  Anyway ... never forget that the standard rules still apply.